# Is there a way to find/generate the architecture or topology of Slurm cluster

Tags: slurm, hpc

I was not able to find anything on slurm documentation (https://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html)

Comment: you did not search at all! https://slurm.schedmd.com/topology.html

Answer (score 3):

The topology can be recovered with the `scontrol` command:

```
$ scontrol show topo
SwitchName=Leaf1 Level=0 LinkSpeed=1 Nodes=node[001-010,021-030,041-044]
SwitchName=Leaf2 Level=0 LinkSpeed=1 Nodes=node[011-020,031-040,061-064,091-094]
SwitchName=Leaf3 Level=0 LinkSpeed=1 Nodes=lm3-w[045-060,065-080]
SwitchName=Root Level=1 LinkSpeed=1 Switches=Leaf1,Leaf2,Leaf3
```

In the above example, we have three leaf switches `Leaf[1-3]`, connected to a main switch named `Root`. The output lists the nodes that are connected to each switch.